# Using Tabler in Laravel

Tags: laravel, twitter-bootstrap, npm, webpack, laravel-mix

I want to use the [Tabler](https://github.com/tabler/tabler) administration panel on Laravel. I'm attempting to install Tabler UI with [npm](https://www.npmjs.com/package/tabler-ui).

```
npm install tabler-ui
```

I add the `tabler` package to `resources/sass/tabler.scss` and then add the SASS file to `webpack.mix.js.`

```js
mix.js('resources/js/app.js', 'public/js')
   .sass('resources/sass/app.scss', 'public/css')
   .sass('resources/sass/tabler.scss', 'public/css');
```

But after trying to `npm run watch,` I got the following error.

> File to import not found or unreadable:
>   ../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss.

When I check the `node_modules/tabler-ui/src/assets/scss/bundle` I find a line which imports the `bootstrap`:

```
@import '../../../node_modules/bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

The error is for this line; I think this line should be like this:

```
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap.scss';
```

I cannot change this line because it is in the /node_modules folder. What should I do to solve this problem?

Answer (score 1):

In your app.scss

replace this:

```
// Bootstrap
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
```

with this:

```
// Tabler
@import '~tabler-ui/src/assets/scss/variables';
@import '~bootstrap/scss/bootstrap';
@import '~tabler-ui/src/assets/scss/dashboard/dashboard';
```

Answer (score 0):

Looks like bootstrap is a peer dependency.

Run `npm install bootstrap` to install it